# Code=9 "Could not create inference context" CoreML iOS

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I am new to CoreMl and following the instruction from [Classifying Images with Vision and Core ML](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/classifying_images_with_vision_and_core_ml) . I ran into an issue while using a model (MobileNetV2) give code from the previous link, I had no issues. When I tried to use my own model that I created using CoreML, I ran into the issue and the localized description was "**Could not create inference context**" when using the iPhone simulator.

```
- some : Error Domain=com.apple.vis Code=9 "Could not create inference context" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Could not create inference context}
```

Answer (score 8):

According to Apple documentation:

> Core ML optimizes on-device performance by leveraging the CPU, GPU, and Neural Engine while minimizing its memory footprint and power consumption.

You see **Could not create inference context** error because Neural Engine is not supported in the simulator.

You can use CPU only for VNRequest in simulator.

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
   request.usesCPUOnly = true
#endif
```

**An update for iOS 17:**

Since `usesCPUOnly` property is deprecated in iOS 17 as mentioned in comment, I tried to find another way. So I ended up with the following solution.

```swift
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    if #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
      let allDevices = MLComputeDevice.allComputeDevices

      for device in allDevices {
        if(device.description.contains("MLCPUComputeDevice")){
          requests[0].setComputeDevice(.some(device), for: .main)
          break
        }
      }

    } else {
      // Fallback on earlier versions
      requests[0].usesCPUOnly = true
    }
#endif
```

Comment: This property is deprecated on iOS 17, any idea about an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

In March 2024, you are able to set just four variants of processing-unit config that **model** can use to make predictions (and you need a case `cpuOnly`). A boolean value for request object, signifying that this request should execute exclusively on the CPU is now deprecated.

```
@available(iOS 12.0, *)
public enum MLComputeUnits : Int, @unchecked Sendable {

    case cpuOnly = 0                  // limits the model to use CPU only
    case cpuAndGPU = 1                // limits the model to use CPU and GPU
    case all = 2                      // the model can use CPU, GPU and NE

    @available(iOS 16.0, *)
    case cpuAndNeuralEngine = 3       // limits the model to use CPU and NE
}


@available(iOS, introduced: 11.0, deprecated: 17.0)
open var usesCPUOnly: Bool            // for VNRequest object
```

---

So now, you can choose the computational mode only in the configurator:

```
let config = MLModelConfiguration()
config.computeUnits = .cpuOnly
    
let mlModel = try! MobileNetV2(configuration: config).model
    
guard let model = try? VNCoreMLModel(for: mlModel)
else { return }
```